# How long does it take for .htaccess changes to take effect?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have added url rewrite rules to my .htaccess file. Should I see these changes working right away?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Changes to .htaccess are immediate and do not require a restart.  Normally, if you aren't seeing what you expect from .htaccess changes, you have a syntax error and should check Apache's logs for some idea of what's going on.

Comment: link to documentation  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html#htaccess

Answer (score 11):

If you use redirect 301, clear browser cache.

Comment: In my case: chrome cache my http to https redirect. If i type the old url in the adressbar, chrome call direct the new url. even though I have switched off the .htaccess redirect again or change it. that can lead to confusion at troubleshooting, so be aware browser cache.

Comment: I've found I had to completely exit incognito mode (all incognito tabs/windows) and then go back into a fresh incognito to properly check each `.htaccess` change. Thank you for this heads up.

Answer (score 7):

NVM [found it](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html#htaccess).

> The .htaccess files follow the same syntax as the main configuration
>   files. Since .htaccess files are read on every request, changes made
>   in these files take immediate effect.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently, some servers only check `.htaccess` files periodically. I've found this to be the case w/ our AWS host.

My source is only a comment below the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9128962/6647188), but it matches my experiences and others seem to agree.

Comment: This matches my experience too. Servers on some web hosting services definitely only check `.htaccess` periodically making it a pain to work with these files on those hosting services.