# Allowing video to be played in <video> element from my website, but not allowing it through direct link

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I used the below tricks:

First, I disabled the right click in order to prevent the user from using `save as` or `get link` using this HTML5:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
</body>
```

Second: I used the `controlsList="nodownload"` but the problem it works fine ONLY in Chrome 58+ as per [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/chrome-58-media-updates#controlslist), later on I may consider customs control as shown [here](https://codepen.io/frytyler/pen/juGfk)

```
<video width="512" height="380" controls controlsList="nodownload"
       poster="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8.gif" >
      <source src="videos/289522.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="videos/289522.ogv" type="video/ogg">
      <source src="videos/289522.webm" type="video/webm">
      Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video tag.
</video>
```

I still need to prevent the user from downloading it in case he got the link by other means, I found some talks about using `.htaccess`, so I created one inside the `videos` folder, and tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://my.domain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.my.domain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .(mp4|mp3|avi)$ - [F]`
```

and used as an alternate way, this:

```
<Files "reminder.php">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from http://my.domain.com/
        Allow from http://my.domain.com/
</Files>
```

But what happened is video had been blocked completely, even from my website itself, and I started getting this error:

> GET http://my.domain.com/videos/289522.mp4 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent downloading images and video files from my website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294501/how-to-prevent-downloading-images-and-video-files-from-my-website)

Comment: Looks like you already found some good solutions to make it harder for your video's to be downloaded.

Comment: Can you confirm that the `.htaccess` you are modifiying is INSIDE the sub-directory with your videos in, AND that you have another `.htaccess` in your project/server root? As sounds like that's causing the issue your getting

Comment: @Lissy yes, you are correct, the one I modified is INSIDE the videos subvolder, and I do have another one in the server root, shall I delete one of them?

Comment: That's correct to have two. And only the one in your media sub-directory should be blocking direct access to video content, so you don't have anything like:  `RewriteRule .(mp4|mp3|avi)$ - [F]` in your main `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## This is possible.

Your .htaccess solution is a good idea, to get it to work, your `.htaccess` needs to be in a sub-directory with the source videos, and nothing else. Update it so that it looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.example.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .(mp4|mp3|avi)$ - [F]`
```

Alternatively this should work too (to completley block access to your video conent)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(mp4|mp3|avi)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

It is required to include both codes together:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(mp4|mp3|avi)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://sample.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

---

*On  a side-note, while we're talking about `.htaccess`, check out this tool for writing and testing your file: http://htaccess.mwl.be/ . It lets you see  which conditions will meet which URL patterns and what the outcome will be, much faster than deploying to your server each time you make a change ;)*

Comment: But this is exactly what I have done, I created ADDITIONAL `.htaccess` file inside my videos folder

Comment: ok, if both your `.htacces` files are correct, see this answer for why it's not refreshing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26181187/979052
I had a similar issue in the past, and somehow Chrome had cached my old file

Comment: ok, tested it out on my server, and got this working fine: 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(mp4|mp3|avi)$ [NC]` - give that a try

Comment: You can make it harder to download, but as this answer notes, ultimately, if it can be viewed it can be downloaded. Even with things like DRM someone could do a screen capture or even record if off the screen if they wanted a copy bad enough. Referers can be spoofed; but that said, most people aren't going to bust out Wireshark and try to figure it out if you put some simple roadblocks in the way.

Comment: I used the second bloc in your answer, and it gave me 403 error in both the link in my website, and in the direct link in the browser bar

Comment: You should only be applying this code to your sub-directory, not your whole domain!

Comment: exactly this what I did, I added the 3 lines in a .htaccess in the videos folder

Comment: And you have a different, correct `.htaccess` in your main/ root folder, right? Can you post it? I tried this code out on my server, works totally fine

Comment: Sorry, I considered one part of your answer that is `%{REQUEST_URI}` once I added the other part, which is `%{HTTP_REFERER}` I got things done. thanks a lot.