# Allowing video to be played in <video> element from my website, but not allowing it through direct URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

FOllowed [Allowing video to be played in <video> element from my website, but not allowing it through direct link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951871/allowing-video-to-be-played-in-video-element-from-my-website-but-not-allowing)

But it's not working for me. It only works on my TEST server which is RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://xx.admin.yy.net/.*$ [NC,OR]

When I move my change to production with the following domains (RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.strategy.domain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://strategy.domain.com [NC]) , The video is not playing at all. No error messages.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(mp4|mp3|avi)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://xx.admin.yy.net/.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www\.strategy\.domain\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://strategy\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

Comment: I get 403 from my website too.. video not loading

Comment: I don’t think your boolean concatenation of the conditions is correct here to begin with. Your first and second condition are joined with an implicit logical AND - so what you have here is true when the first two conditions match together, or when the third or fourth match _on their own_.

Comment: _“The video is not playing at all. No error messages.”_ - did you verify that your browser actually does send a referrer in that case to begin with? (Use browser dev tools, network panel, to check.)