# .htacces worked only the first time

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a nooby question.
I'm working on wampserver on localhost to test redirection.
I made a .htaccess on the project root and it worked perfectly.

**.htaccess**

```
Redirect permanent /blog/ http://foo/
```

But now, I would like to change the `.htaccess` by

```
Redirect permanent /blog/ http://foo/blog/
```

And nothing happens...I mean it's still the same redirection even if I write this :

```
Redirect permanent /blog/ http://abcedfgh/foo/
```

I saw there is [no problem of refresh with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126247/can-i-force-htaccess-to-refresh).

I tested Ctrl+F5 and Ctrl+Alt+r to clean browser cache without success.

Someone has got an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

To clean the broswer cache, Ctrl+F5 or Ctrl+Alt+R is not enough !
I had to go in options browser.

For Firefox : [information is here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache)

Comment: 301 redirects are cached by Web browser. Whenever you are testing a Redirect or RewriteRule for url redirection you should always use a `Temporary` 302 redirect status to avoid this browser cache problem.