# This web page has a redirect loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, error-handling

Alright so I tried forcing either www. or allowing without the www. . It wasn't working so I took it all out of the .htaccess file and re-uploaded. Now when I try to view the website I get the error message of:

> This web page has a redirect loop

How long does this take to refresh and not display this error message anymore? I tried clearing my cookies and flushing my DNS. It's still there.

Thank you!

Comment: You've cleared your browser's cache?

Comment: @JonLin: Yes, I cleared the Browser Cache and my DNS Cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe have a look at this previous question's answers: [How long does it take for .htaccess changes to take effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836845/how-long-does-it-take-for-htaccess-changes-to-take-effect)

Changes to .htaccess should take effect immediately. It might help to re-check the obvious things (that the file on the server is indeed the correct .htaccess, etc)

Apache's help page on the matter: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html#htaccess