# htaccess not working in subdomain but same works in domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I had htaccess which works for `domain.com` and not works for `sub.domain.com`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

All suggestions appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it should work for all domains and sub-domains. After creating the new sub-domain you should wait until the sub-domain is live. After the waiting time it automatically works for me.

Comment: You do not have to wait for an update to an .htaccess file. [They update instantaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836937/2341603).

Comment: @ObsidianAge yes you are correct. But for new sub domain you need to wait until the sub domain is propagated.